# Optimize Sieve of Eratosthenes in MIPS

Tags: mips, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have made some progress in optimizing code for the Sieve of Eratosthenes, but I need to do so further to improve instruction count and data cache hit rate.  Any help is appreciated.

```
    .data           # the data segment to store global data
space:  .asciiz " "     # whitespace to separate prime numbers

    .text           # the text segment to store instructions
    .globl  main        # define main to be a global label
main:   li  $s0, 0x00000000 # initialize $s0 with zeros
    nor $s1, $s0, $s0   # saves one ALU count over using li $s1, 0x11111111
    li  $t9, 200    # find prime numbers from 2 to $t9

    add $s2, $sp, 0 # backup bottom of stack address in $s2

    li  $t0, 2      # set counter variable to 2

init:   sw  $s1, ($sp)  # write ones to the stackpointer's address
    add $t0, $t0, 1 # increment counter variable
    sub $sp, $sp, 4 # subtract 4 bytes from stackpointer (push)
    bne     $t0, $t9, init  # take loop if $t0 != $t9, changed ble to bne
    addi    $t8, $t0, 15    # approximate square root of 200
    li  $t0, 1      # reset counter variable to 1

outer:  add     $t0, $t0, 2 # increment counter variable (start at 2)
    mul $t1, $t0, $t0   # squaring $t0 and save it to $t1
    bgt $t1, $t8, print # start printing prime numbers when $t1 > $t8, changed so only bgt if $t1 > square root

check:  add $t2, $s2, 0 # save the bottom of stack address to $t2
    sll $t3, $t0, 2 # calculate the number of bytes to jump over
    sub $t2, $t2, $t3   # subtract them from bottom of stack address
    add $t2, $t2, 8 # add 2 words - we started counting at 2!

    lw  $t3, ($t2)  # load the content into $t3

    beq $t3, $s0, outer # only 0's? go back to the outer loop

inner:  add $t2, $s2, 0 # save the bottom of stack address to $t2
    sll $t3, $t1, 2 # calculate the number of bytes to jump over

    add     $t4, $t1, 2 # save $t1 + 2 into $t4, added
    sll     $t5, $t4, 2 # mul by 4, added

    sub $t2, $t2, $t3   # subtract them from bottom of stack address

    add $t2, $t2, 8 # add 2 words - we started counting at 2!

    sw  $s0, ($t2)  # store 0's -> it's not a prime number!

    add $t1, $t1, $t0   # do this for every multiple of $t0

    add $t1, $t1, $t0   # adding $t0 to $t1, added
    sub $t2, $t2, $t5   # save $t2 - $t5 into $t2, added
    add $t2, $t2, 8 # adding 8 to $t2, added
    sw  $s0, ($t2)  # store contents of $s0 at address contained in $t2, added
    add $t4, $t4, $t0   # adding $t0 to $t4, added

    blt $t1, $t9, inner # every multiple done? go back to outer loop, changed to blt and branching to inner

    j   outer       # some multiples left? go back to inner loop, changed to branching to outer

print:  li  $t0, 1      # reset counter variable to 1

    # hard coding a 2
    li  $v0, 1
    addi    $a0, $a0, 2
    syscall

    # hard coding a space
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, space
    syscall

count:  add $t0, $t0, 2 # increment counter variable (start at 2), skipping even numbers

    bgt $t0, $t9, exit  # make sure to exit when all numbers are done (branch to exit if $t0 > $t9)

    add $t2, $s2, 0 # save the bottom of stack address to $t2
    sll $t3, $t0, 2 # calculate the number of bytes to jump over
    sub $t2, $t2, $t3   # subtract them from bottom of stack address
    add $t2, $t2, 8 # add 2 words - we started counting at 2!

    lw  $t3, ($t2)  # load the content into $t3
    beq $t3, $s0, count # only 0's? go back to count loop

    add $t3, $s2, 0 # save the bottom of stack address to $t3

    sub $t3, $t3, $t2   # substract higher from lower address (= bytes)
    srl $t3, $t3, 2 # changed div to srl
    add $t3, $t3, 2 # add 2 (words) = the final prime number!

    li  $v0, 1      # system code to print integer
    add $a0, $t3, 0 # the argument will be our prime number in $t3
    syscall         # print it!

    li  $v0, 4      # system code to print string
    la  $a0, space  # the argument will be a whitespace
    syscall         # print it!

    bne $t0, $t9, count # take loop when $t0 != $t9, changed ble to bne

exit:   li  $v0, 10     # set up system call 10 (exit)
    syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

The first optimisation would be to code the algorithm in C/C++ and to apply due diligence (cleanup/tightening of the code). If that's not fast enough, start applying the usual optimisations for the Sieve of Eratosthenes:

- use a packed bit array instead of representing a number by a byte or word
- use an odds-only sieve (pulling the prime 2 out of thin air when needed)
- sieve in small, cache-friendly segments (e.g. 32KB L1 cache on many CPUs)
- remember offsets between segments to avoid costly modulo divisions
- initialise segments with the bit pattern corresponding to sieving by a handful of small primes
- dispatch segments for sieving to all available cores in parallel

[Sieve of Eratosthenes - segmented to increase speed and range](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69791/sieve-of-eratosthenes-segmented-to-increase-speed-and-range) shows a clean and lean implementation of a segmented sieve and explains these optimisations (except for multithreading); it also has links to compilable test programs demoing these optimisations.

Assembly coding can improve the speed of a plain C implementation of the sieve by only about 10%, unless the C compiler is unusually poor. In real-world numbers, this means the C version may take 15 seconds to sieve the numbers up to 2^32 and the assembler version may take 13 seconds. Applying the first five optimisations from the list above takes the C version down to about 2 seconds, and adding the last can get you to less than a second (about 0.3 if you have 8 idle cores).

If that is not fast enough then assembly coding will likely be no help, since nowadays optimisation is more about reducing contention, avoiding the latencies of deep memory cache hierarchies and keeping pipelines well fed with instructions ready to be executed (instead of waiting for dependencies). I.e., optimisation wars are won on the algorithmic and architectural level, not with assembly micro-optimisations. Current compilers tend to very good at applying micro optimisations automatically, like instruction scheduling, avoiding branch mis-prediction penalties etc. pp. When hand-coding assembly one needs to work quite hard to even reach the speed of compiled code, let alone surpass it.

The next level of optimisation would be to extend the idea of the odds-only sieve to excluding more of the small primes (3, 5, 7 and so on). That's usually called a 'wheel'. However, the gain from adding more spokes gets smaller and smaller. The two-spoke wheel (odds-only sieve) already cuts work in half, but adding 3 to the picture removes only a further third and so on while making the code quite a bit more complicated. The complications will likely make the code slower than the odds-only version, so you need to go to higher-order wheels to see a significant improvement.

In any case, optimisations need to be prototyped and reference-implemented in a high-level language anyway, something that's human-readable like e.g. C/C++ and doesn't require interpretation by a high priest of MIPS.